# Liquor tree drag and drop - how to prevent drop/create a parent node from a dragged child node (Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, tree

I have parent nodes with child nodes. Child nodes can be dragged and dropped to any parent node of its child nodes(child nodes to child nodes only), but i should not create parent node after drag and drop of child node(child node should not be created as a parent node).

How could i restrict create a new parent node in the tree. Thank you for reading. Much appreciable if someone gives me a solution. I googled and couldn't find any solution for this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Drag & Drop</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/liquor-tree"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <tree
      :data="treeData"
      :options="treeOptions"
      @node:dragging:start="logDragStart"
      @node:dragging:finish="logDragFinish"
    />
  </div>
  <script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: () => ({
          treeData: getTreeData(),
          treeOptions: {
            propertyNames: {
              text: 'MY_TEXT',
              children: 'KIDS',
              state: 'OPTIONS'
            },
            dnd: true,
            checkbox: true
          }
        }),
        
        methods: {
            logDragStart(node) {
            console.log('Start dragging: ' + node.text)
          },
          
            logDragFinish(targetNode, distinationNode) {
            console.log(`Stop dragging: [TARGET]${targetNode.text}`)
          }
        }
      })

      function getTreeData() {
        return [
          {
            MY_TEXT: 'PARENT1',
            OPTIONS: { draggable:false},
            KIDS: [
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent1 - Child1' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent1 - Child2' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent1 - Child3'},
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent1 - Child4'}               
              ]},
               {
            MY_TEXT: 'PARENT2',
            OPTIONS: { draggable:false},
            KIDS: [
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent2 - Child1' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent2 - Child2' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent2 - Child3'},
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent2 - Child4'}               
              ]},
               {
            MY_TEXT: 'PARENT3',
            OPTIONS: { draggable:false},
            KIDS: [
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent3 - Child1' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent3 - Child2' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent3 - Child3'},
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent3 - Child4'}               
              ]},
               {
            MY_TEXT: 'PARENT4',
            OPTIONS: { draggable:false},
            KIDS: [
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent4 - Child1' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent4 - Child2' },
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent4 - Child3'},
              { MY_TEXT: 'Parent4 - Child4'}               
              ]}
              
        ]       
        
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify the drag option
If the destination is at the top level, disable drag and drop
However, if only the top level is blocked, the child element cannot be moved to another parent node.
so Requires a non-'drag-on' condition

```
dnd: {
    onDragFinish(targetNode, destinationNode,postion) {
    if(destinationNode.depth == 0 && postion !='drag-on'){return false;}
      return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.